# How To Stop Notification From Popping Up On A Single Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-notifications

So I'm building an app that has one activity (MainActivity) and using fragment to run the app.

I have a notification that is called in MainActivity.

When I tap on the notification, it will bring me to a specific fragment.

The problem I'm having is that the notification always shows up every time I click on the notification. How do I stop this notification from popping up?

Here's my MainActivity

```
package com.main.netwallet

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.main.netwallet.addTransaction.AddTransactionFragment
import com.main.netwallet.database.NetWalletDatabase
import com.main.netwallet.databinding.FragmentReminderBinding
import com.main.netwallet.initialSetting.AddNewAccountFragment
import com.main.netwallet.reminder.ReminderFragementViewModel
import com.main.netwallet.reminder.ReminderFragementViewModelFactory
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val PREF_KEY_EMAIL = "email preference"
    lateinit var sharedPreferenceEmail : SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var drawerID : DrawerLayout
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        
        //add bottomNavigation
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bn_main)
        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.addTransactionFragment)
        }

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        /**
         * These lines of codes below to check destination changed
         */
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if(destination.id == R.id.loginFragment){
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                fab.visibility = View.GONE
            }else if(destination.id == R.id.registerFragment){
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                fab.visibility = View.GONE
            }else if(destination.id == R.id.initialSettingFragment) {
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                fab.visibility = View.GONE
            }else if(destination.id == R.id.addTransactionFragment){
                fab.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        sharedPreferenceEmail = getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY_EMAIL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val getEmail = sharedPreferenceEmail.getString("email_preference", null)
        val application = requireNotNull(this).application
        val dataSource = NetWalletDatabase.getInstance(application).netWalletDatabaseDao
        val viewModelProvider = ReminderFragementViewModelFactory(dataSource, application, getEmail.toString())
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProvider).get(ReminderFragementViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getReminderDate.observe(this, Observer { list->
           list?.let {
               for (i in 0..list.size -1) {
                   if (i >= 0){
                   val getReminderDate = list.get(0).getReminderDate
                   val todayDate: String =
                       SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
                    val compare = getReminderDate.equals(todayDate)

                   if (getReminderDate == todayDate) {
                       notif()
                       Log.e("Notif", getReminderDate)
                       Log.e("Notif", todayDate)
                       Log.e("Notif", compare.toString())
                   }
               }
               }
           }
        })

        val toNotifFragment = intent.getStringExtra("toNotifFragment")
        if (toNotifFragment.equals("NotifFragment")){
            findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.transactionNotificationFragment)
        }

        Log.e("Activity", "Main Activity")
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        when(menuItem.itemId){
            R.id.logout -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, LogoutActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.account ->{
                findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.accountFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.homeBottom ->{
                findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.settingBottom ->{
                findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }

    fun notif(){
        createNotificationChannel()

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra("toNotifFragment", "NotifFragment")
            .apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent : PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, 0)

        var notifBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24)
            .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
            .setContentText("This is sample notification")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)){
            notify(1, notifBuilder)
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
            val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID",name,importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }

            val notificationManager : NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

The solution that I'm pretty sure would work is to create an activity that responds to a notification's tap. But before I'm going that way, I want to know if there is any way to keep it in a single Activity

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to show the notification when the activity is **not** opened via the pending intent declared as the notification `ContentIntent` only. This can be done easily by moving `notif()` method call to the else statement of the if clause:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

val toNotifFragment = intent.getStringExtra("toNotifFragment")
if (toNotifFragment.equals("NotifFragment")) {
    findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.transactionNotificationFragment)
} else notif()
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely share the code because I thought it was too long. I've updated the source code of MainActivity.

The thing is, there is a process to get a data, which is a date, from database and compare it to date today. If it's equal, then show the notification.

https://pastebin.com/v5nk7G7W

So, when I click on the notification and brings me to transactionNotificationFragment, which is part of MainActivity, the notification will always show as long as date from database is equal to today. So is there any other solution? I've tried above code but didn't work